# How to exclude links when using Adobe s_code.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-analytics

I have a site which is tracked by Adobe Omniture, it loads s_code.js to track the site.

My site also have a full screen slide function, when click Next, it will show a short animation and replace with the next slide. But when put the s_code.js and use s.t(), the animation disappeared. (I think there should be some code conflict.)

Does anyone know how to let s_code to exclude the links like Next? For example, Next button has id as nextbutton.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi Jai, can you provide more details about closure? Like an example. Thanks.